# Why is the nontrivial left ideal of $M_ 2(D)$ minimal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm totally confused by this question. I appreciate any help or answer. thanks in advance
why is the nontrivial left ideal of M_2(D) minimal? that D is a division ring

Answer (score 0):

$M_2(D)$ has a composition length of $2$. This is one such composition series:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\subseteq \begin{bmatrix}0&D\\0&D\end{bmatrix}\subseteq M_2(D)
$$

It's easy to check that the module in the center is a simple left $M_2(D)$ module. Since you can find a composition series through any nontrivial left ideal, we see that every nontrivial left submodule is both a minimal left and maximal left ideal.

Comment: thank you...
 you said that it's easy to see the module in the center is simple. but I didn't get it how

Comment: @MojtabaMohamadpour Show that given any $\begin{bmatrix}0&x\\0&y\end{bmatrix}$ and nonzero $\begin{bmatrix}0&w\\0&z\end{bmatrix}$ there is a matrix $A$ such that $A\begin{bmatrix}0&w\\0&z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&x\\0&y\end{bmatrix}$. That shows it is simple.